# How to restrict the user to access only few pages using angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Here suppose i have 10 pages but i want to restrict some users to access only 3 to 4 pages among 10 pages. How can i achieve this using angularjs 2. Please help me with a sample application with static data. Thanks ..

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards#

Comment: you have to configure routes.

Comment: please post a complete sample code

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'product-details',
  template: `
    <div>
      Showing product details for product: {{id}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class LoanDetailsPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  id: number;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private __userType: UserTypeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       console.log(params); // you will get which router is being redirected
        if(__userType.type.hasAllowed){
            // service to get is user allowed to redirected..
        }

    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i don't have much knowledge on angular. So could you please share complete working sample code link here. So that i can understand. ThanQ.. waiting for your reply